# greasemonkey simple string manipulation

Tags: greasemonkey

I need a little help to write a simple greasemonkey script to help me with a task.
I have a an url with a number like this:

```
www.something.com/item/4563/
```

and I want to extract this number from the url, convert it to integer variable (called item_number) so I can use it in this simple code to generate link to pages with previous and next items:

```
var links = document.createElement("div");
links.innerHTML = '<a href="http://www.something.com/item/' + (item_number-1) + 
'/">Previous</a> <a href="http://www.something.com/item/' + (item_number+1) + 
'/">Next</a>';
document.body.insertBefore(links, document.body.firstChild);
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = "www.something.com/item/4563/";
var matches = url.match(/item\/(\d+)/);
var itemNumber = matches && parseInt(matches[1], 10);
console.log(itemNumber); // => 4563
```